# Change Background of DataGridCell in relevance to its content

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, background, datagridcell

I know that my question was stated and answered in several ways here already. But I just can't get it to run the way I would like.
As the title states, I try to change the background color of my datagridcell depending on its content. 
I am relatively new to WPF, but I guess the solution is a converter combined with a binding.
The goal is to change the background colour of the cell in dependence of a property called "Status", which is an enum with four states.

I already wrote a converter:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows;

namespace Admin
{
    [ValueConversion(typeof(Member.UserStatus), typeof(Brushes))]
    public class StatusToColorConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        #region IValueConverter Member

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var enumValue = (Member.UserStatus)value;

            if(enumValue == Member.UserStatus.Change)
                return Brushes.Red;
            if(enumValue == Member.UserStatus.Import)
                return Brushes.Blue;
            if(enumValue == Member.UserStatus.Remove)
                return Brushes.Orange;
            if(enumValue == Member.UserStatus.Synced)
                return Brushes.Green;
            else
                return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

So far so good.
The xaml part looks like this (after some googling...)

```
<DataGrid.Columns>              
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Status">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Status}" Background="{Binding Status, Converter={StaticResource StatusToColorConverter}}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

I don't really get (yet) what DataGridTemplateColums and DataTemplates are. But I tried the same with CellStyle and another way that I can't remember.
The converter has a breakpoint and gets called in all solutions I tried. But somehow the "Background" property seems to ignore the return value from the converter. So I guess my fault (or my lack of understanding) has another source.

Anyone care to point me in the right direction?

Comment: What your current solution does, is it selecting full row ? have you tried setting SelectionUnit="Cell" for datargid and styling the DataGridCell ?

Comment: styling the cell was one of the solutions I tried (at least i think so), same result: Converter gets called but the background property does ignore the value. Could you post (or link) me an example how such a DataGridCell Style could look like in XAML?

Comment: try two things: 1- Does binding works? try the break-point in converter and see whether 'enumValue' get the desired value. 2- see the output window while running in debug mode to see any related message.

Comment: @Naser Asadi: yes. The binding works in a way that at least the converter gets, and returns the right values. It just seems that the returned brush is ignored by the background property. Thanx for the hint regarding the output window. I often forget about that. It doesn't  bring up any error messages though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok guys. I have the problem solved now.
The problem wasn't my xaml code. The converter worked also fine. The Problem was the following line in the converter .cs file:

```
    using System.Drawing;
```

I replaced it with the correct one:

```
    using System.Windows.Media;
```

And now it works like a charm.
...
I was passing Brushes for WinForms instead of WPF Brushes!

Thanks for all the help anyway :)

Comment: Wow. Funny how nobody noticed that :)

Answer (score 3):

If I interpret your XAML correctly - you are painting the column HEADER (the "topmost" cell), not the cell itself.

This works for me:

```
<DataGrid.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Status},
                       Converter={StaticResource StatusToColorConverter}">
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
</DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

This should paint your cell

As a side note: Your cells might look "weird" if you are painting their Background - my cells often lose their Borders etc. A quick and easy fix is to add the following Propertie Setters (it is the default wpf style)

```
 <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,0,1,1"></Setter>
 <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF000000"></Setter>
```

Comment: I just reread your code: Do you want only to paint the STATUS column, but no other Column? If so, you need a Multibinding - I have the code for it, so say if you need it.

Comment: do you mean: `   <DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
     <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Status, Converter={StaticResource StatusToColorConverter}}">
     </Setter>
    </Style>
   </DataGrid.CellStyle>` ? Doesn't work either.

Comment: I want to paint the cells in the Column 'Status' individually regarding their content.

Comment: Sorry for the "it doesn't work". Well the converter gets called, with the correct values, and it even returns the correct brush... But Still the same: The brush seems to be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

I did it this way:

```
              <DataGrid.CellStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                        <Setter Property="Background">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <Binding Path="Row" Mode="OneWay" />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

Note that I am using DataView as ItemsSource to DataGrid and therefore I bind to "Row". Item is than basically DataRowView. Then you need to access row values in the converter:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
        var enumValue = (Member.UserStatus)((DataRow)value)["Status"];
        if(enumValue == Member.UserStatus.Change)
            return Brushes.Red;
        if(enumValue == Member.UserStatus.Import)
            return Brushes.Blue;
        if(enumValue == Member.UserStatus.Remove)
            return Brushes.Orange;
        if(enumValue == Member.UserStatus.Synced)
            return Brushes.Green;
        else
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }
```

Comment: Where do i implement the converter in this solution? XAML syntax is still confusing to me.

Comment: @Mathew Well how did you implement it in your case? Do it the same way.